# PyQGIS doesn't load user libraries properly

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to put my PyQGIS functions in separate .py files and load them from my main script.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def getVectorLayerGeo():
    
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    layers = project.mapLayersByName('Yalcowinna')
    layer = layers[0]
    features=layer.getFeatures()

    coords = list()
    
    for feature in features:
        geom = feature.geometry()
        geomSingleType = QgsWkbTypes.isSingleType(geom.wkbType())
        if geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry:
            if geomSingleType:
                x = geom.asPoint()
                print("Point: ", x)
            else:
                x = geom.asMultiPoint()
                print("MultiPoint: ", x)
        elif geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
            if geomSingleType:
                x = geom.asPolygon()
                print("Polygon: ", x, "Area: ", geom.area())
            else:
                x = geom.asMultiPolygon()
                print("MultiPolygon: ", x, "Area: ", geom.area())
        else:
            print("Unknown or invalid geometry")

    for coord in x[0][0]:
        coords.append([coord.x(),coord.y()])
        
    return coords
    
print(getVectorLayerGeo())
```

does exactly what it's supposed to, which is print a list of coordinates (as lists).

Then I try to call `getVectorLayerGeo` from another script:

```py
import ee
from ee_plugin import Map
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from get_layer_coords import getVectorLayerGeo

vizParams = {'bands' : ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], 'min':0, 'max':10000}
geom = ee.Geometry.Polygon(getVectorLayerGeom())
S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
image = S2.filterBounds(geo).first()

Map.addLayer(image, vizParams, 'Sentinel-2')
Map.centerObject(image, 10)
```

and I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.16\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Glen Shennan/Google Drive/African Lovegrass/ShannFlat\get_layer_coords.py", line 56, in <module>
    print(getVectorLayerGeo())
  File "C:/Users/Glen Shennan/Google Drive/African Lovegrass/ShannFlat\get_layer_coords.py", line 18, in getVectorLayerGeo
    geomSingleType = QgsWkbTypes.isSingleType(geom.wkbType())
NameError: name 'QgsWkbTypes' is not defined
```

The thing is, when I copy `getVectorLayerGeo` into my main script it works as intended. Obviously I have the solution for this case but I'm intending to write a lot of functions and I don't want to put them all in one giant script.

`QgsWkbTypes` is part of qgis.core, but when I `import qgis.core` at the start of `get_layer_coords.py` script it doesn't seem to help. Am I doing something wrong or does QGIS not like calling functions from other .py files?

Comment: You haven't imported `QgsWkbTypes` anywhere in the module.  Try `from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsWkbTypes`.

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thanks. The thing is, when I run the module stand alone I don't need to do the import. Why is that?

Comment: Must be automatically available in the main scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't imported `QgsWkbTypes` anywhere in the module. Try:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsWkbTypes
```